# WebView Facebook authorization

Tags: android, facebook, authorization, android-webview

In my app I need to add logging via facebook.
For this purpose I got a page on my server which redirects me to facebook login page, where I enter user credentials, then it comes back to my page and returns auth data.
What I want to do is to open a webview in my app, open my page (which redirects to facebook) and when after login it returns me some token I need to close webview, get the data from it and proceed in my app. But I cant make it.
Can anyone give me links to some examples of such an authorization mechanism? And how do I get data from a webview?